# Return Multiple Values through Function using C Program

Tags: c, string

I am trying to write a function that returns multiple values including a string. I used pointers since I saw that's the way to do it and it worked but only with the int part. I can't figure out why it's not printing the string. There are no errors, only the string is not being printed.

This is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
void Example(char str[50], char *str2[50], int *maximum )
{
 int x=5 , y=2 ;
 strcpy(*str2 ,str);
 *maximum = x+y ;
}
int main()
{
   char str[50], str2[50];
   int maximum;

   fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

   Example(str, &str2, &maximum);
   printf("%s %d", str2, maximum); //Its not printing the string for some reason 
}
```

Comment: What string are you expecting to be printed? You completely omitted the important part, namely how you are writing to this array

Comment: @UnholySheep I just edited it. Im not sure if this is how it should be

Comment: `Example(str, &str2, &maximum);` There should be one big compiler warning here. The function expects a `char**` as the second argument, but you are passing a `char*`. Also, you don't need to pass a `char**` argument. Change `char *str2[50]` to `char str2[50]` and `strcpy(*str2 ,str);` to `strcpy(str2 ,str);`.

Comment: This `char str[50]` makes no sense - it is a `char *` as arrays degrade into that.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, strings in C are arrays which are pointers.
So `char str[50]` is a pointer to an array of 50 bytes. While `char *str[50]` is  pointer to an array of 50 pointers each to an arbitrary array of chars.

So in order to return a string from a function, you don't have to declare it as a pointer, to a pointer, you would be fine with just `char str2[50]`.

```
void Example(char str[50], char str2[50], int *maximum )
{
 int x=5 , y=2 ;
 strcpy(str2 ,str);
 *maximum = x+y ;
}
int main()
{
   char str[50], str2[50];
   int maximum;

   fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

   Example(str, str2, &maximum);
   printf("%s %d", str2, maximum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using pointers there is no need for `char *str2[50]` since `char *str2` will work.

When it comes to the  `strcpy(*str2 ,str);` since it takes 2 pointers to strings as arguments just use `strcpy(str2 ,str);`

So in the end your code should look like this:

```
void Example(char str[50], char *str2, int *maximum )
{   
 int x=5 , y=2 ;
 strcpy(str2 ,str);
 *maximum = x+y ;
}
int main()
{
   char str[50], str2[50];
   int maximum;

   fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);
   
   

   Example(str, str2, &maximum);
   printf("%s %d", str2, maximum); 
 
   
   return 0;
}
```